# Postfix client sasl 465 bounced 550 sender rejected (in reply to MAIL FROM command)

Tags: ssl, postfix, smtp

I'm tring to send an email through my mail provider but I get rejected, is there something wrong with my config file ?

```sh
echo "Hello" | mail -s "hi" you@example.com
```

Gives me

> status:bounced 550 sender rejected (in reply to MAIL FROM command)

Here is my postfix main.cf

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = noanonymous

compatibility_level = 2

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = my.host.name
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, my.host.name, my, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = [my.smtp.provider]:465
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
```

And sasl_passwd looks like

```
[my.smtp.provider]:465 log@in.com:password
```

Answer (score 0):

You should post a complete log, with so few information it's a bit difficult.
Anyway, without reading the log, I assume the error is generated by my.smtp.provider smtp server, that do not recognize the FROM it receive as a valid sender.